# Do Monte Carlo perturbations capture all the uncertainty in prediction?

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, monte-carlo, uncertainty, error-propagation

I have a model $M$ that I use to predict a value $y = M(\vec x)$. I have known one-$\sigma$ error bars on each input $x_i \in \vec x$. I want to know the one-$\sigma$ error bar on my prediction $y$.

Since in my special case I know all uncertainties $\vec \sigma$ on my inputs $\vec x$, I can perturb each input $x_i \in \vec x$ with random noise having mean 0 and standard deviation $\sigma_i$. I can do this $n$ times to obtain $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n$. I can then apply my model to each of these randomly perturbed inputs to obtain $$y_j = M(\vec x + \vec \epsilon_j)\qquad j=1,\ldots,n.$$

Now I can take the median and standard deviation of $\vec y$, and I have one-$\sigma$ error bars on $y$.

But wait! Doesn't this only account for the uncertainty in my inputs $\vec x$, and not the uncertainty in my model $M$? If $M$ is an oracle and gives the correct answer every time, this seems fine. But in practice, this won't be the case. So how do I account for the uncertainty in each prediction made by $M$?

Does it differ depending on whether I am using a linear model, a neural network, a random forest regressor, etc?

I imagine what I really need to do is obtain a prediction interval for each $y$ and then take medians of the lower, middle, and upper bound of the interval. Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: 1. You mention uncertainties on inputs, but I note that some of the models you mention are not suitable for cases with uncertainties on inputs (e.g. regression, at least the usual kind, is one example). 2. Are you talking about a) the uncertainty because the parameter estimates are not their true values, b) the noise in the process that relates known inputs to observed outputs, c) the uncertainty/error introduced by using model $M$ when the actual process is model $M'$, or d) something else?

Comment: Assuming your model *M* is correct, a couple of observations: first, since you are using *L2-norms* or squared errors to estimate the deviations, it seems odd to switch to an *L1-norm* metric such as the median. Why not use the mean throughout? Or, alternatively, use an appropriate *L1-norm* measure of uncertainty such as MAD throughout? Second, I could be wrong but the uncertainty built into your model is rooted in the historic information or data used in the simulations. To @Glen_b's point, what about the uncertainty in the model's parameter estimates?

Comment: The model is trained using simulations, which have no errors in the inputs; and it is now being tested on real observations, for which we can obtain measurement uncertainties.

Comment: I could use the mean throughout. There was no particular reason for me to change to the median.

Comment: @Glen_b question 2, I am wondering about a, b, c, and d! I don't think we can handle cases c and d, and maybe not case a, but case b seems tackleable.

Comment: We can assume that I am trying to build the best possible model -- the model being built isn't supplied by an adversary. When I cross-validate on my training data, I get a very good R^2.

Comment: Clearly model uncertainty could be a major issue. Some possible ways of trying to address it is to use multiple models and model averaging, in many situation this tends to perform better than using a single model as given when we are not really sure this is the "single true model". One thing that is very hard to do anything about is the situation where the situation you are predicting about is far outside the situations you have data about. In that setting empirical models that are not based on a correct theoretical understanding of the physical/biological/etc. system will not predict well.

Comment: Is there anything that you can inherently say about the model-uncertainty of a black box model? If you don't know anything about the structure or the parameters, then how can you even discuss the model-uncertainty? If the model is *not* a black box, then you can include the parameters in the MC sampling, but that doesn't help you with structural uncertainty: There is no way to sample structure (except by placing subjective restrictions on which structures are viable).